# Visualize the decision border (frontier) of my special SVC model using scikit learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, plot, scikit-learn, svm

I'm discovering the world of Machine Learning, and I'm working on a SVC model, studying cancer.

I have two data files, one for X, one for y. My y file contains only binary values (1 or 0) corresponding to each value of my X file. So if it is 1, it means the patient is sick.

I've plot my data with that code :

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.loadtxt('X')
y = np.loadtxt('Y')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20)

svclassifier = SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
svclassifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = svclassifier.predict(X_test)
plt.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], c=y_train, cmap='winter', s=20, edgecolors='k')
plt.show()
```

It gives me this :
[Visualizing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9AEM.png)

Then, I'm calculating `w` and `b` for my border with this :

```
w = svclassifier.coef_[0]
b = svclassifier.intercept_
```

I saw that I could use this to plot the border :

```
plt.plot(SOMETHING,-w[0]*SOMETHING/w[1]-b/w[1],'k')
```

But I don't see what to put. How could I plot the border here?

Comment: @desertnaut  The link you gave me, I get this https://imgur.com/a/WApiqkH
It's not the result I'm waiting for

Comment: If so, please open a new **reproducible** question (i.e. with dummy/random data, as in the link), explaining in detail what you did and did not work (you can include a link here and/or to the duplicate thread). Please also notice that there are several different answers in the duplicate thread.

Comment: Ok but I don't know how to adapt these answers to my case, that's why I need help
I'll open a new question